# PHP Login Script Broken

Tags: php, sql

Hello Ladies and Gentlemen, I have been working on this project for some time now. And all of a sudden when I go into the web page to login I just get a blank screen at the 'success_login.php' which is literally just the login script that runs once login is clicked on my screen.

Here is the success_login.php script:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/luke/classes/userFunctions.php');
$userFunctions = new userFunctions();

session_start();
//assign all posted values to a session
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION['login_info'][$key] = $value;
    }
}
//Get the username and password
$username = htmlentities($_POST["username"], ENT_QUOTES); 
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"], ENT_QUOTES);

//Get the user id if the login was valid
$userId = $userFunctions->validLogin($username,$password);

if($userId != 0) {
    $_SESSION['login_info']['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['login_info']['password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['login_info']['user_id'] = $userId;
    header('LOCATION: home.php');
    exit;
}
header('LOCATION: login.php');
exit;
?>
```

and here is the function it refers to:

```
        public function validLogin($username,$password) {
        $dbact = new DbInteraction();

        $query = "select * from person";
        $result =  $dbact->interact($query,true);
        $row = mysql_numrows($result);

        $valid = false;
        $userId = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            //Check to see if the username and password are valid
            $validUsername = strcmp($username,$row['username']);
            if($validUsername == 0) {
                $hashedPassword = md5($password . Constants::SALTED);
                $validPassword = strcmp($hashedPassword,$row['password']);
                if($validPassword == 0) {
                    $valid = true;
                    $userId = $row['idperson'];
                }
            }
        }

        if(!$valid) {
            $_SESSION['login_info']['username'] = "error";
            $_SESSION['login_info']['password'] = "";

            header('LOCATION: login.php');
            exit;

            return $userId;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['login_info']['username'] = "";
            $_SESSION['login_info']['password'] = "";

            return $userId;
        }

    }
```

Like I said, its been working for months and now all of a sudden its not anymore, and it has me really worried. Could someone shed some light for me?

Thanks a million for your time!

Comment: Have you changed the code OR the enviroment? Like Php Edition or other things?

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? Maybe is your PHP version changed?

Comment: If it's the exact same code, and it suddenly stopped working, then the environment must've changed. Contact your host and find out what they recently upgraded.

Comment: put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors',1)` at the beginning of your script, it will trigger the errors and help you to debug, but as others said, it's probably the php version triggering any error and stopping the script, and not showing the error because of the php's setting.

Comment: As far as I know nothing has changed. Its hosted here on my local network, and my boss wouldve told me if something changed. All I've been doing recently is adding functionality to the webpage, never touched these two scripts for a long time though.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You really should learn how to use `WHERE` clauses in SQL. You're doing the equivalent of buying the ENTIRE inventory of a store, trucking it home, rummaging through all that stuff, picking out and eating the ONE candybar you wanted, then tossing everything else in the garbage.

Comment: Alrighty I got her working again. Thanks guys!

Comment: @MarcB OP is avoiding SQL injection :p